# React.js New Line and Returns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, newline

I'm calling an API that responds with items (objects) that have the general form:

```
{
    "comment":"Here is a comment that has a new line \n, a return \r and a tab in it for this item: \r\tSome Item"
}
```

This gets added to the react app:

```
<Item>{item.comment}</Item>
```

The problem is the new line, tab and returns aren't included. Does anyone know a syntax where this will be respected without a monster search and replace (this API returns thousands of these records, I'd prefer not to have to iterate over each one to insert `"<br />"` etc).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
import React from 'react';


//styles
import './index.css';

/**
 * Used to preserve whitespace for text values. For instance, \n, \r, and \t characters
 * @param {Object} props
 * @param {string} props.text The text you want to preserve whitespace from. 
 */
function PreserveWhitespace({text}) {

    return (
        <span className="preserve-whitespace">
             {text}
        </span>
    );

}

export default PreserveWhitespace;
```

And the CSS:

```
.preserve-whitespace {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think ReactJS supports this out of the box. I found something that you can use here - [Newline in react string](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/newline-in-react-string-solved/68484)